# Skype not working

Tags: skype

I downloaded the latest upgrade in May 2012, and as always, I experienced some issues. My Skype is no longer working. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall and it still locks up every time I try to use it. I've tried logging onto Ubuntu with the previous version and it still won't work. Are there any solutions for someone who has limited knowledge of Linux?

Comment: May I know your kernel and skype version? copy paste this and run in terminal : uname -a ; skype --version

Answer (score 4):

You could try to delete the old Skype folder (where some settings are stored). Open your filemanager, press `CTRL+H` to view hidden files and folders. You will see the **.Skype** folder, delete or rename it to something different. Then start Skype again.